# Extra White Space on Wordpress website To the right

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor, right-to-left

White Space on Wordpress website to the right when switching to rtl in elementor specific pages
Here is webpage :
[site url](https://leaderexpress-1-c5b9fc.ingress-daribow.ewp.live/ar/about-us/)

tried

```
html,  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.rtl .elementor-top-section {
    left: 0 !important;
    width: auto !important;
}
```